# Why does Material Design Toolbar have this strange padding?

Tags: android, material-design, android-toolbar, layoutparams, android-layoutparams

In my `ToolBar` with `android:padding=0dp`, and in it I have a single `LinearLayout` with `android:width=match_parent` and `android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"`. So at least width-wise, no part of the `Toolbar` (colored black in this example) should show on the sides of the `LinearLayout` (colored red in this SSCCE).

**The problem is that the Toolbar is showing on the left side of the child LinearLayout.** How do I make the LinearLayout span the entire Toolbar so that no part of the Toolbar shows?

[image]

***MainActivity.java:***

```
package tests.example_one;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Toolbar toolbar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.mainActivity_appBar);

        setSupportActionBar(toolbar); 
    }

}
```

***res/layout/activity_main.xml:***

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="@dimen/fullBackgroundPadding" >


    <include layout="@layout/app_bar"
        android:id="@+id/mainActivity_appBar" />

</LinearLayout>
```

***res/layout/app_bar.xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/appBarHeight"
    android:background="#000"
    android:padding="0dp" >


    <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#F44336"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp">

    </LinearLayout>


</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

***res/values/dimens.xml***

```
<resources>

    <dimen name="fullBackgroundPadding">8dp</dimen>

    <!-- App Bar -->
    <dimen name="appBarHeight">48dp</dimen>

</resources>
```

Comment: Toolbar is already a LinearLayout. So you don't need to add a LinearLayout but rather just the child views that you would like to show.

Comment: @SteveC. But it doesn't extend LinearLayout, rather directly extends ViewGroup

Comment: Thats interesting because when I tried your app_bar layout in android studio, the design tab shows it as a LinearLayout. I was able to remove the LinearLayout you declared and add multiple child views within the toolbar and run it and it worked perfectly. May I ask what it is that you are trying to achieve by adding a LinearLayout?

Comment: @SteveC Just some Views (icon, textfield) added to Toolbar horizontally one after the other. I checked the reference for `Toolbar` and saw that it does not inherit from LinearLayout. SO I thought I was supposed to add the LinearLayout into it.

Comment: @SteveC. I tried removing the LinearLayout. It didn't help. See the accepted answer. That is what that black part is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That black part is the inset the Toolbar applies to its content. Add the following two lines to your `Toolbar`'s XML:

```
app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
```

Also, don't forget to the `app` namespace.

So you are essentially changing your app_bar.xml from

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/appBarHeight"
    android:background="#000"
    android:padding="0dp" >


    <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#F44336"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp">

    </LinearLayout>


</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

to

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/appBarHeight"
    android:background="#000"
    android:padding="0dp"
    app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
    app:contentInsetLeft="0dp" >


    <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#F44336">

    </LinearLayout>


</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```